# Why doesn't "The Wolf Among Us - Season Pass" appear in my download list after purchased in the PSN?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus, the-wolf-among-us

I have purchased The Wolf Among Us - Season Pass last night, but couldn't find it in my download list. But the product page shows it as purchased. Also Do I need to purchase the "The Wolf Among Us : Episode 1" game too? (Which costs few more bucks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:**

Its take time to reflect the price in psn. Now all the available seasons are marked as FREE. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Season Pass does not include the first episode. You need to purchase the first episode separately. Here is the description for the Season Pass on xbox.com. I assume it's the same for PSN:

> Buy The Wolf Among Us Season Pass for the best value and get all 4
>   remaining episodes (Episodes 2-5 to be released periodically) in the
>   5-part series once available to download. All Season Pass content will
>   be available by Summer 2014. If you purchase this Season Pass, all
>   future Season Pass content will be accessible in-game once available.
>   Do not download from the Xbox Games Store, or you will be charged
>   twice. The Wolf Among Us - Episode 1: Faith game required; sold
>   separately.

Comment: The Wolf Among Us will launch on PS3 in North America on Tuesday October 15, with a European release date still to be confirmed. Individual episodes will cost $4.99, while a season pass including episodes 1-5 will be priced at $19.99.

Comment: For Xbox 360 and PC, priced at $4.99. On Microsoft’s console, the rest of the series (episodes 2-5) will be available at a discounted price of $14.99 as part of a season pass, versus the regular $4.99 episode price.